# Can I freeze pre-cooked chicken?

Tags: chicken, meat, freezing

I am looking for a way to precook chicken and preserve it for later use. The idea being that I precook the chicken (1 hour at 150 C) then freeze it, then when I need it, defrost and pop onto the flame grill, then baste and season. Secondary cooking/grilling will be around 10  minutes.

Issue would be freezer burn. So can I use a brine, or oil or something to stop freezer burn (if I can even do the rest of this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can freeze cooked chicken.  Freezer burn is dehydration...moisture loss in the freezer.  Your best protection is good packaging.  If you can vacuum seal your packages, that will be your best defense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, safely.
So long as it's cooked to safe temperature all the way through & then sealed in a bag/box you should be able to avoid freezer burn; which is moisture evaporating off the food due to the atmosphere in a freezer being technically 'dry'.

My worry would be overcooking at the reheat, not as a safety issue, just one of texture.
Legs & thighs tend to be better at surviving a long or double cook. Breast can get a bit stringy, dry & chewy. Skin on survives better than skinless for this.